# Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove that $\langle\,,\rangle : \mathscr H \times \mathscr H \to \Bbb C$ is continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, hilbert-spaces, alternative-proof

Let $(a,b) \in \mathscr H \times \mathscr H$ be fixed.

So we have to prove that for a given $\epsilon \gt 0$, we can find $\delta_1 \gt 0$ and $\delta_2 \gt 0$ such that $\lvert \langle x,y\rangle - \langle a,b\rangle\rvert \lt \epsilon$ whenever $\lVert x-a\rVert \lt \delta_1$ and $\lVert y-b\rVert\lt \delta_2$ and to do this we have to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $\lvert \langle x,y\rangle\rvert \le \lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert$.

(Note that "$\langle\,,\rangle$" denotes the inner product and "$\lVert \cdot\rVert$" denotes the norm induced by it.)

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given.

Then, I start with

\begin{align}
\lvert \langle x,y\rangle - \langle a,b\rangle\rvert &= \lvert\langle x,y\rangle - \langle a,b\rangle + \langle x,b\rangle - \langle x,b\rangle\rvert = \lvert\langle x,y-b\rangle + \langle x-a,b\rangle\rvert\\
&\le \lvert\langle x,y-b\rangle\rvert + \lvert\langle x-a,b\rangle\rvert \le \lVert x\rVert \lVert y-b\rVert + \lVert x-a\rVert \lVert b\rVert.
\end{align}

Now I choose $\delta_1=\frac {\epsilon}{\lVert b\rVert}$ and $\delta_2=\frac {\epsilon}{\lVert a\rVert}$.

Hence, $\lVert x\rVert - \lVert a\rVert  \le \lVert x-a\rVert \lt \delta_1$ and $\lVert y-b\rVert \lt \delta_2$

$\Rightarrow$

$\lvert\langle x,y\rangle - \langle a,b\rangle\rvert \le (\lVert a\rVert + \delta_1)\delta_2 + \delta_1 \lVert b\rVert = \bigl(\lVert a\rVert + \frac {\epsilon}{\lVert b\rVert}\bigr)\frac {\epsilon}{\lVert a\rVert} + \epsilon = 2\epsilon + \frac {\epsilon^2}{\lVert a\rVert \lVert b\rVert}$.

So we conclude that $\langle\, ,\,\rangle$ is continuous.

Am I on the right track so far? Is there a more simpler way to do this (Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality obviously.)?

Comment: This is right, and I don't think you can do anything to simplify it. You could play around with the choice of $\delta$ to end up with just $\epsilon$ if you're being picky.

Comment: @mathematician In case of continuity, $\delta$ always depends on the point(as well as on $\epsilon$) at which we are checking the continuity.So in this case, $\delta_2=\delta_2(\epsilon,b)$ and not $\delta_2=\delta_2(\epsilon,x)$.

Comment: Yup, as soon as I posted I realized that.

Comment: A simpler (looking) way would be using the sequential criterion of continuity in which case you will be done at the first step of equalities and inequalities if you replace $x$ by $x_n$, $y$ by $y_n$ where $(x_n,y_n)\to (a,b)$.